# Wrap an exception in a message without throwing it

Tags: c#

I'm writing a service which's methods must not throw exceptions but should return a generic `Message`-object which contains the actual result of the method call and exceptions if any have occured. This `Message` class looks like this:

```
public class Message<T>
{
    private List<Exception> exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    public T Result { get; set; }

    public void AddException(Exception x)
    {
        this.exceptions.Add(x);
    }

    public bool HasExceptions
    {
        get
        {
            return this.exceptions.Count > 0;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Exception> Exceptions
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (var exception in this.exceptions)
                yield return exception;
        }
    }
}
```

Usually the implementation of a service method then looks like this:

```
public Message<int> MyServiceMethod()
{
    var msg = new Message<int>();

    try
    {
        // do something useful here
        msg.Result = 42;
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
       msg.AddException(x);
    }

    return msg;
}
```

The caller can then handle exceptions if necessary.

```
var msg = service.MyServiceMethod();
if (msg.HasExceptions)
{
   // Handle exceptions here
}
```

Now I have a service method with an argument which must be in a certain range. Since it feels natural for me to respond with an  `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the argument is out of range, I implemented it like this:

```
public Message<int> MyOtherServiceMethod(int arg)
{
    var msg = new Message<int>();

    if (arg < 1)
    {
        msg.AddException(new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("arg", "Argument must be greater than 0"));
        return msg;
    }

    // ...
    return msg;
}
```

Basically this works. The only thing I'm missing is the stack trace of the exception. This is not a problem since I don't need that in my scenario. But it made me wonder, are there any other "side effects" which might cause trouble when the exception is used but not thrown?

Comment: Did you try it and what was the result?

Comment: it kind of depends on how you are using it later. Are you interested in the complete stack trace of the exception?

Comment: You do not need to throw and catch it, they way you are currently doing will work. Altough, it it was me, I would do add some description in the exception.

Comment: @RosdiKasim however, there will be no stacktrace in the exception if it's just newed. A thrown exception will have it though.

Comment: Why are you putting Exceptions inside Messages? Shouldn't it be the opposite as always (that is, Exceptions _containing_ message strings)?

Comment: @Default I already tried and it worked. As you stated, the stack trace is missing and this made me wonder whether there are other side effects. I rephrased my question accordingly.

Comment: @heltonbiker please se my edit. My methods mustn't throw exceptions, instead exceptions sould be wrapped in a message object together with the actual result.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some construction that takes `message` and `exception` as arguments:

```
try
{
    // do something useful here
}
catch (Exception x)
{
   throw YourPreferredException(some_message, x);
}
```

This will make `x` available as `yourPreferredException.InnerException` property.

Also, I don't think it's a good design choice to have a method returning `Message` and running the `try/catch` block *inside* it (should be the other way around).

Comment: the question seems to ask if he needs to do "throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException", catch it and then continue, or if he can just do new ArgumentOutOfRangeException. I'm not sure how your answer explains that. Also, the last sentence isn't valid - the OPs code example *returns* a `Message`, it doesn't state that it is being executed i the `Message` class.

Comment: I meant "method" instead of "class". Corrected.

Comment: Corrected again, thanks. The bad design I mention is to have a Message containing an Exception, instead of the universally expected opposite (that is, Exceptions containing Messages, or better yet, message Strings.)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that's not really the intended use of exceptions in C#. If you want a custom message then you just use the `Exception` constructor that takes a message and another instance of type `Exception`, this will give you a new exception with your custom message plus the original exception set as the instances `InnerException` property. You're just reinventing the wheel here with some custom 'message' class. If all you want to do is return a message (like you don't want to throw) then you should be taking the exceptions `Message` property and assigning it to some string or returning that string directly.

Here are a couple more idiomatic examples for handling your error;

```
Message ret = new Message();
try
{}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ret.ErrorPropertyOfTypeString = e.Message;
}
return ret;


Message ret = new Message();
try
{}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception("My custom message here", e);
}
return ret;
```

Whatever you're doing, one of the two patterns above should probably used instead.